# выполние кода при закрытии страницы | jqeury show modal on close page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не получается вызвать `alert` при закрытии страницы.
Не понимаю в чем беда, помоги пожалуйста. Искал в ***Google***, но так и не нашел нормального решения.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
    function loadPage() {
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        alert("пока");
      }
      alert("Привет");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadPage()">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt eveniet, quos velit, eius sapiente, ea neque cupiditate doloribus, tenetur nemo quis iste porro magnam. Veniam vero, laboriosam voluptas laborum neque!</p>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      window.onunload = function() {
        alert(0);

      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vikopot/pen/QJvVgO)

Comment: https://habr.com/post/141793/ как я понял адекватный текст вы там не выведите.

Comment: спасибо что пролили свет на эту проблему, а можно тогда другим образом (не через onbeforeunload ) решить данную задачу? есть ли похожее событие? мне нужно показать юзеру модалку при уходе со страницы

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {

    // возвращает cookie с именем name, если есть, если нет, то undefined
    function getCookie(name) {
      var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
        "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
      ));
      return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    }

    var mouseY = 0;
    var topValue = 0;
    var count = 0;
    window.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){
        mouseY = e.clientY;
        if(mouseY<topValue && count === 0) {
                if( getCookie('popup_close_show1') == undefined )
                {
                    //1раз
                    //alert("Do something here!!!");
                    jQuery('.class').trigger('click');


                    document.cookie = "popup_close_show1=1";

                }
                else if( getCookie('popup_close_show1') == 1 )
                {
                    //2й раз
                    //alert("Do something here!!!");
                    jQuery('.class').trigger('click');


                    document.cookie = "popup_close_show1=2";
                }

            count ++;
        } 
    },
    false);
})();
```